# What is the name of this object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var myObj = { fName: "John", lName: "Doe" };

function myName(f) {
  console.log(f.fName + " " + f.lName);
}
myName({fName: "Mary", lName: "Jane" });
```

^ What is the the name of this anonymous obj? Does it have a name? Can we add more props?

Comment: Javascript objects have no concept of a name.

Comment: A more elaborate description would probably be useful.

Comment: Are you referring to the object that your're passing to the myName function?

Comment: In your example, `l` is `undefined` btw. Did you mean to use `f.lName`? Or call the function with `myName({fName: "Mary", lName: "Jane" }, myObj)`? So many  uncertainties...

Comment: And, do you actually try to update object myObj (ok, it is not a name, it is reference, right:))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, objects don't have names.

Another thing to note, your code doesn't work as-is.  You would get the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'lName' of undefined or null reference
```

Here is what you'd want to do:

```
function myName(f) {
  console.log(f.fName + " " + f.lName);
}
myName({fName: "Mary", lName: "Jane" });
```

In your original example, you're passing an object (single, first param) to the `myName()` function.  In the scope of the function, you have `f`, which is your object.  `f.fName` and `f.lName` are defined.  But `l` isn't passed (and doesn't seem to be your intentions).

The changes made change the function signature from `function myName(f, l)` to `function myName(f)`, and then in the body of the function, changing `l.lName` to `f.lName` to properly referenced the desired object.

> Can we add more props?

What exactly do you mean?  Where?  Assuming a certain amount of your intentions here, yes you can:

```
function myName(f) {
  console.log(f.fName + " " + f.lName);

  // add the formatted name in the form of "LastName, FirstName"
  //
  f.formattedName = f.lName + ", " + f.fName;
  console.log(f.formattedName);
}
myName({fName: "Mary", lName: "Jane" });
```

**Edit**:  SerCrAsH (comment) brings up a good point.  You could always return your object from the function:

```
function myName(f) {
  console.log(f.fName + " " + f.lName);
  f.formattedName = f.lName + ", " + f.fName;
  console.log(f.formattedName);

  return f;
}

var name = myName({fName: "Mary", lName: "Jane" });

console.log(name.formattedName);
```

Comment: "anonymous objects" ... I hope this doesn't become a thing. Objects don't have names, therefore every object is "anonymous".

Comment: @FelixKling Ha! Good catch, looks like my brain injected that word in there unintentionally.  Thanks!

Comment: Still have no idea why he needs to work with an object wich have a reference only inside the function, maybe in `myName` could be there a `return` with the object `f` modified like as a constructor method adding some properties to the object.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Note that another way of getting rid of the runtime error would be to write `myName({fName: "Mary"}, {lName: "Jane" });`, but I'm sure that's not what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a name. Objects never have names. Sometimes there are variables or properties containing references to an object and variables and properties have names.

You can add more properties to it either by editing the source code where it is created or by getting a reference to it (such as the `f` variable in `myName`) and editing it using that.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Please explain the difference between "anonymous objects" and "objects" (-> it doesn't make sense).

Comment: *Some* objects, in general, are named and some are not.  Inside the function, that object has the name `f`. Outside of it, the object is anonymous.

Comment: @Blazemonger — No, inside the function a variable named `f` contains a reference to the object. The object itself is nameless. (A function can have a name, but a plain object cannot).

Comment: Technically true, however I think it's likely from the context that OP was looking for a variable name that refers to the object.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Well, there is also no way to get the names of all variables that refer to the object.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, I misunderstood the first part of Quentin's answer the first half-dozen times I read it, and I'm *not* a newcomer to the language. While true, it's not very clear. Nor is it, I think, very helpful to OP.

Answer (score -5):

You can named whatever you want. In the bests cases you can name it as according what the object have to-do.

Example, if you want a object that refers to a Customer, you would do:

```
var Customer = { id: 1, name: "Quentin", age: 999 }
```

Same if you need a Product object

```
var Product = { id: 999, description: "aois jdpoaisjd paosijd as" }
```